# Existe um equivalente expressão a "out of town"?

Tags: expressões, expressões-idiomáticas, informalidade

A tradução literal seria "fora da cidade", mas tem algumas outras maneiras de dizer isso?

Comment: Você poderia adicionar alguns exemplos de uso de 'out of town' para nos dar contexto?

Comment: Além de **viajando** que o Carlos sugere em sua resposta, há também simplesmente **fora** e, noutro contexto, mais uma tradução possível é "forasteiro" (e.g., *Out-of-town folks aren't welcome.* - "Forasteiros não são bem-vindos.", ou "Gente de fora não é bem-vinda.").

Comment: Kaleb, deverias incluir um exemplo de frase. Tens traduções diferentes para "out of town" dependendo se é  "Jeniffer is out of town", "the stadium is out of town", "out-of-town folks" ou "the main road out of town".

Comment: @stafusa e outros: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou incluir mais exemplos a próxima vez.

Comment: @kalebo podes incluir nesta pergunta, basta [editá-la](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/5374/edit). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor tradução que consigo pensar seria "está viajando". Por exemplo
"Jeniffer is out of town" -> "Jeniffer está viajando" ou "Jeniffer viajou".